# Office Add-in, add gallery component like Quick steps to ribbon

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, outlook-addin, ribbon-control

I want create Outlook add-in with custom gallery component like "Quick steps".

### [image]

I created Outlook 2013 and 2016 VSTO add-in project. I added ribbon designer and gallery component to there. But I don't know how can I restyle it like "Quick steps"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not all controls/styles are available for developers. The full list of controls and their properties are described in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

This style (in-ribbon) gallery control is not supported by Office. Please refer to Office Development reference: [Creating Dynamic Ribbon Customizations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd548011%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on what can you do with Gallery control.